# Custom device frame in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a webapp which will be used on an embedded touch screen device. The screen is 854x480.

I created a custom emulated device in Chrome Dev Tools using that resolution. Is it possible to also add a custom device frame border? Some default devices have a frame border, for example the "Nest Hub". I'd like to add my own device border as a jpg or png. Is that doable?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was possible in the past. I have not found any solution for it in the last 20-30 chrome releases. It appears the custom background is no longer an option.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33148006)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).